Нужна ли закрывающая запятая после оборота с "которых", или она съедается тире?
Появились боли, которых раньше никогда не было — головные и желудочные.

Правильно:
Появились боли, которых раньше никогда не было, — головные и желудочные.
Пояснение
Здесь можно применить общее правило пунктуации о независимой постановке знаков: В большинстве случаев каждый из знаков препинания ставится на собственном основании. Об этом говорит Розенталь: § 64. Запятая и тире, пункт 1.
В данном случае запятая закрывает придаточное определительное, и тире ставится в главном предложении для обособления определения с пояснительным значением:
Появились боли (какие именно?)  — головные и желудочные.
